# sed command to remove a string and everything after it in that line

Tags: linux, unix

**The .cpp file in a directory contains this text:**

```
/**
 * Performs the standard binary search using two comparisons per level.
 * Returns index where item is found or or the index where it chould
 * be inserted  if not found
 */
template <typename Comparable>
int binarySearch( const Comparable* a, int size, const Comparable & x )
{
  int low = 0, high = size - 1;     // Set the bounds for the search

    while( low <= high )
    {
      // Examine the element at the midpoint
      int mid = ( low + high ) / 2;

       if( a[ mid ] < x )
         low = mid + 1;  // If x is in the array, it must be in the upper
       else if( a[ mid ] > x )
         high = mid - 1; // If x is in the array, it must be in the lower
       else
         return mid;   // Found
    }
    // Return the position where x would be inserted to
    // preserve the ordering within the array.
    return low;
}
```

**Using  the unix sed command, how would I print the contents of the .cpp file above with all the inline comments strings deleted (which look like this: // ) and all the text after it in that row deleted? I put an example below of what I am looking for. All the // marks and everything after them on that row is gone in this desired output.**

```
/**
 * Performs the standard binary search using two comparisons per level.
 * Returns index where item is found or or the index where it chould
 * be inserted  if not found
 */
template <typename Comparable>
int binarySearch( const Comparable* a, int size, const Comparable & x )
{
  int low = 0, high = size - 1; 

    while( low <= high )
    {

      int mid = ( low + high ) / 2;

       if( a[ mid ] < x )
         low = mid + 1;  
       else if( a[ mid ] > x )
         high = mid - 1;
       else
         return mid;
    }

    return low;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use `sed`, this can be done easily with `grep`:

```
cat file.cpp | grep -v \/\/
```

Explanation:

`grep -v` will print all lines that don't match the pattern, and the pattern `\/\/` is just an escaped version of `//`

If you do need to use `sed`, this can still be done easily (it's just arguably not the right tool for the job, and [quite a bit slower](https://lyness.io/the-functional-and-performance-differences-of-sed-awk-and-other-unix-parsing-utilities)).

```
cat file.cpp | sed '/\/\//d'
```

This matches every line that starts with `//` and deletes it.

Answer (score 0):

To remove every line that contains "//":

```
sed '/\/\//d' file.cpp
```

To remove "//" and all that follows it on the line:

```
sed 's|//.*||' file.cpp
```

To do both (i.e. remove the "//" and all that follows it on the line, and remove that whole line if nothing but whitespace came before it):

```
sed '/^ *\/\//d;s|//.*||' file.cpp
```